# Calculate average from XML elements

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have an xml file structured around

```
<user>
    <name>Fred</name>

    <test1>23</test1>
    <test2>34</test2>
    <test3>43</test3>
</user>
```

there are about 20 records with the same data.
I am trying to use vb.net 2015 community edition to average the tests over all users eg add up the test 1 to 3 for each user and divide by number of users.

Is anyone able to help me with code for a button event to write to a label the class average?

Comment: Well, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml

Comment: Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/linq/scope-of-default-namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work for you:

```
   'Dim xDoc = XDocument.Load("Your Document path")'

    Dim xDoc =
        <Document>
            <user>
                <name>Fred</name>
                <test1>23</test1>
                <test2>34</test2>
                <test3>43</test3>
            </user>
            <user>
                <name>Greg</name>
                <test1>50</test1>
                <test2>50</test2>
                <test3>50</test3>
            </user>
        </Document>


    Dim result = (From node In xDoc.Descendants("user")
                  Select (Convert.ToInt32(node.Descendants("test1").Value()) +
                        Convert.ToInt32(node.Descendants("test2").Value()) +
                        Convert.ToInt32(node.Descendants("test3").Value()))).Average()
```

Comment: ((23+34+43) + (50+50+50)) / 2 = 125. Code gives me correct result.

Comment: hi - if you average each user overall and then find the average of their average that is what I am after and it should read directly from the xml file

Comment: Then uncomment the line loading data from the file and change the formula as you need. What's the problem?

Comment: it throws an exception

Comment: The problem is my xml which is generated automatically by Visual studio and it is the line with the users.xsd